# What is this trap in QGD?

Tags: queens-gambit, trap

I recently watched an Eric Rosen video where he showcased a trap in the QGD. I do not remember what the trap was called. Here are the moves.

```
[FEN ""]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Bg5 Nbd7 {The trap is this move, because the d5 pawn is not actually free} 5. cxd5 exd5 6. Nxd5 Nxd5! {And White falls for it!} 7. Bxd8 Bb4+! 8. Qd2 {White is forced to give up their queen since that is his only move} Bxd2+ 9. Kxd2 Kxd8 {Black is up a knight, and has a safer king than White, and White’s only compensation is a pawn. Lichess’s Stockfish rates this to be ~-3.}
```

I don’t remember the name of the trap. If anyone could let me know that would be great. (Bonus points for anyone who can link me the Eric Rosen video!)

Comment: Naroditsky's also shown it at least twice in his speedrun, the most recent mention being from [a discussion about a game at the rating of 1940](https://youtu.be/VEwKZo8l7yY?t=695).

Comment: What's the best response to this? simply not taking the pawn with the knight?

Comment: @asaf92 According to stockfish, the best move is 6.e3. Stockfish gives a rating of .4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is known as the [Elephant Trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen%27s_Gambit_Declined,_Elephant_Trap).

Answer (score 7):

This trap is the Elephant Trap.

The video is:

[Crazy Queen's Gambit Declined and Secret Preparation Revealed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OP_-UHafujw)